# Distribution of a sample drawn from distinct Poisson distributions

Tags: distributions, mean, conditional-probability, central-limit-theorem

I have a sample $X = \{\mathbf{x}_i\}$, where each $\mathbf{x}_i$ has a set of discrete features $x_{j}$ and a value $y_i$. I'm interested in the distribution of the sample mean, $\bar{\mathbf{y}}$ - but wait, there's a catch!

I know the conditional probability distributions over each feature - or rather, for each feature $x_j$ taking some value $k$, I know the population subgroup means $\mu(j,k)$, and I can assume that the value statistic is Poisson distributed:

$y \sim Poisson(\mu(j,k))$

However, I know nothing about the joint distributions of the features - for example, $P(y|x_1=a, x_2=b)$.

Given a sample with a known breakdown over each feature (i.e. $|\{\mathbf{x}_i : x_{j} = a\}|$ is known for all $j$), but no information about the size of the intersections between features, what can I say about the distribution of the sample mean $\mathbf{\bar{y}}$? How can I define it based on the various $\mu(j,k)$?

To give a concrete example: let's say I'm interested in the number of sexual partners per person, averaged over a sample. I know the average number of partners for men, and the average number for women. I also know the average number of partners for people living in rural vs urban areas, but I do not know the average for urban-dwelling men, etc. I have a sample of size $n$. I know that the sample contains $a$ men and $b$ women, where $a+b=n$; and $x$ rural and $y$ urban dwellers, where $x+y=n$. I do not know how many urban men, rural women etc. are in the sample. I want to describe the sampling distribution of the sample mean.

EDIT: Here's an explanation based on my actual problem.

The statistic I'm interested in is absence from work, in days per person. The group means are from results published by the national statistics office (the ONS). The ONS publish breakdowns (by sex, age bracket, industry sector, region, full-time vs part-time, etc.) and a small number of intersections where they are confident in the sample size (e.g. by sex and age bracket). I'm interested in a sample with a known feature-breakdown - e.g. a random group of 30 people, of whom a) 12 are men and 18 are women; b) 5 are aged 16-24, 15 are aged 25-34, and 10 are aged 35-49; etc. What can I say about the sampling distribution of the sample mean - i.e. the distribution of days of absence per person, averaged over the 30 people - in terms of the means of the various breakdowns?

Comment: It doesn't look like you have enough information to answer the question. The marginal expectations $E[y|x_i]$ alone do not allow you to calculate the expectation $E[y|x_1,...x_n]$.

Comment: If you assume a linear model, then you can solve this, but would a linear model be correct for your application?

Comment: How is it that you know the means for single features, but not for combined features? How did you do your measurements? Why can you assume a Poisson distribution? If you have two Poisson distributions for the groups $$X_{a,man} \sim  (\mu(1=,2=man))$$ and $$X_{a,woman} \sim  (\mu(1=,2=woman))$$ then you assume that the combination of those two $$X_a \sim (\mu(1=))$$ but it can *not* be Poisson distributed. The mixture of two Poisson distributions (with different means) is not a Poisson distribution.

Comment: The group means are from results published by the national statistics office (the ONS). The actual statistic I'm interested in is absence from work, in days per person. The ONS publish breakdowns (e.g. by sex, age bracket, industry, region) and a small number of intersections where they are confident in the sample size (e.g. age bracket X sex), but for the most part the breakdowns are by a single feature at a time. I'm interested in a sample with a known feature-breakdown - e.g. a group of 30 people, of whom a) 12 are men and 18 are women; and b) 10 are aged 16-24 and 20 are aged 25-35

Comment: In reality a Poisson is a simplification. A Poisson mixture model might give a better fit, but I don't have enough information to parameterise one. I've tried using a negative binomial with n=265, but this doesn't fit the data well. However, I don't think this should matter when it comes to the sample mean, which I suspect should be normally distributed, I'm just not sure how to calculate the mean and variance. One idea is to calculate $E[X] = E[ E_{x|\lambda}(X) ]$ and $V[X] = V[ E_{x|\lambda}(X) ] + E[ V_{x|\lambda}(X) ]$ over each feature breakdown, and then take the mean of the results

Comment: When you ask about "sampling distribution" you have to define the sampling process. Do you mean that you are going to randomly select exactly the same number of people from each group (e.g. 5 women aged 16-24, 3 men aged 25-35, etc.) ?